# How can I fix this python problem with lists

Tags: python

```
num1 = [int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())]
for i in range(0, 3):
    if num1[i] == int(8) or int(9):
        print("Ignore")
        print(num1[i])
        break
```

Just wondering for this code, I input 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 for the list. And it returns and prints ignore, but the for loop looping the first 4 numbers which do not equal to 8 or 9. Can someone please explain this phenomenon thanks.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not image.

Comment: DO NOT use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then format it as code. This helps others more easily read and test your code. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: u can do `num1=[]` `for i in range(8):` `num1.append(int(input()))` , then the next forloop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 3 you say

```
if num1[i] == int(8) or int(9)
```

The problem with this is that python splits the boolean as `(num[i] == int(8)) or (int(9))`

`int(9)` is True (all non-zero numbers default to True) so your program will `print("Ignore")` no matter what the number is

Comment: You can also do [int(input()) for _ in range(8)] instead of the first line.